# Übersetzung von "let me drop everything to work on your problem"

Tags: english-to-german

Die wörtliche Übersetzung von

> Let me drop everything to work on your problem!

ist

> Lass mich alles fallenlassen, um an deinem Problem zu arbeiten!

Ich finde das doppelte "lassen" unschön. Gibt es eine alternative Übersetzung?

Um etwas Kontext hinzuzufügen: Der Satz ist ironisch gemeint, und richtet sich primär an Kollegen, die mit angeblich dringend zu erledigenden Aufgaben zu mir kommen. Ich habe ihn auf einem T-Shirt, und überlege, eine deutsche Version anfertigen zu lassen.

Comment: Ist es ironisch gemeint?

Comment: Es ist ironisch gemeint. Den Satz hab ich auf einem T-Shirt, das ich raushole, wenn mal wieder jeder irgendetwas Dringendes erledigt haben will.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Statt Wort für Wort zu übersetzen, braucht man hier das passende Idiom:

Aus *drop everything* wird *[alles stehen und liegen lassen](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/alles+stehen+und+liegen+lassen.html)*.

Gleichzeitig formuliert die englische Sprache oft etwas „subtiler“ als die deutsche, vor allem bei Anweisungen, so dass man auch „direkter“ formulieren kann, um das erste *lassen* loszuwerden, dann aber kontextabhängig:

> - Ich kann (ja) alles stehen und liegenlassen …
>     (Aussage, auch ironisch)
> - Soll ich alles (einfach) stehen und liegenlassen …
>     (Frage, Angebot oder Ablehnung)

Comment: i would typically say "alles _andere_ stehen und liegen lassen".

Comment: Hm. Das bringt mich auf Ideen in der Richtung "Ich lass doch *gern* alles stehen und liegen, um an deinem Problem zu arbeiten!"

Answer (score 3):

Ich nehme an, dass die Frage an den Vorgesetzten gerichtet ist, der das genehmigen muss (andernfalls bitte Frage präzisieren):

> Darf ich alles andere liegen lassen, um mich um dieses Problem zu kümmern?

Comment: In der Frage steht kein Fragesatz.

Comment: Als Frage an den Chef würde ich es ebenso übersetzen. Gemeint ist der Satz aber anders, ich habe meine Frage erweitert.